# Program quits if pipe is closed

Tags: c++, pipe

I am trying to write to a pipe using C++. The following code gets called in an extra thread:

```c
void writeToPipe()
{
    int outfifo;
    char buf[100];
    char outfile[] = "out";

    mknod(outfile, S_IFIFO | 0666, 0);
    if ((outfifo = open(outfile, O_WRONLY)) < 0) {
        perror("Opening output fifo failed");
        return false;
    }

    int currentTimestamp = (int)time(0);
    int bufLen = sprintf(bug, "Time is %d.", currentTimestamp);
    write(outfifo, buf, bufLen);
}
```

The thread is called in main using:

```
thread writeThread(writeToPipe);
writeThread.detach();
```

If the pipe is not opened by another process, the C++ program just quits without an error. I don't know how to check if the pipe is opened.

Comment: Do you catch `SIGPIPE` at all?

Comment: Maybe this compiles in a C++ compiler, but this is not necessarily C++.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams No, that was the solution I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: `sprintf(bug,...)`: oh, the irony.